# How to find the request for a particular response while using tornado library?

Tags: request, tornado, httpresponse, http-get, asynchttpclient

This is a reduced version of the code.I and making over 100 requests using http_client.fetch, I am getting the responses in random order,It is really important for me to know which response is for which request that I made.What changes should I make in order to achieve this?

```
from tornado import ioloop, httpclient
def handle_request(response):
    jsonobject_ticker = json.loads( response.body, object_hook= JSONObject)
    currency_price=jsonobject_ticker.result.Last
    print "{0:.9f}".format(currency_price)
    global i
    i -= 1
    if i == 0:
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

def check_for_pump():
    for index in range (len(shortlisted)):      
        market=shortlisted[index]
        print market

        http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        global i
        i += 1
        http_client.fetch(get_ticker_url(shortlisted[index]), handle_request, method='GET')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTPResponse object [has a "request" property](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.5.1/tornado/httpclient.py#L556), so you can just access `response.request` in your callback.

More generally, however, if you wanted to pass specific data to a callback you can use a "partial":

```
from functools import partial

def handle_request(data, response):
    ...

data = "foo"
callback = partial(data, handle_request)
http_client.fetch(url, callback)
```

You don't need this technique in this case, but it's good to know how to pass data to a callback in Tornado.

Comment: thanks Davis ! that worked for me perfectly ! :D I used the "partial" method as you mentioned.